# How to delete a CheckBox from a TableView in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing a seating chart program using JavaFX. I have a table that keeps a list of students together that holds their name, grade, and whether they are present or absent (using a checkbox). I have a delete button that allows me to delete the students from the list. This works fine, however, whenever I delete the student object, the checkbox does not go along with it. I'm not sure what I would need to add to get that to work. Here is a snippet of the delete code. There are also two images below that show my problem. This is my first post so please let me know if I missed something. Please help! Thanks!

```
ObservableList<Student> items, sel;
items = currentTable.getItems();
sel = currentTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
Student s = new Student("", "", 0, "");
for (Student p : sel) {
    items.remove(p);
    s = p;
}
```

Before Delete

[image: [Before Delete]

After Delete

[image: [After Delete]

Comment: what is the structure of Student class? Is Present? is a part of student class?

Comment: When one of the checkboxes are selected, a boolean called selected within student is updated to be true or false. Selected has a setter method and a get method as well.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm just trying to delete the row regardless of whether it's selected or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `delete` or `remove` method. It has to do with what you did in `TableColumn.setCellFactory()`.

To get the checkbox you shown, you should have used (in general) one of the two methods:

#### Overriding updateItem() in TableCell while setting Cell Factory

There is this `empty` parameter in `updateItem()` which indicates whether the row is empty or not. You need to use that to determine when not to show the checkbox.

```
column.setCellFactory(col -> {
    return new TableCell<Foo, Boolean>() {
        final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

        @Override
        public void updateItem(final Boolean selected, final boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(selected, empty);

            if (!this.isEmpty()) {
                setGraphic(checkBox);
                setText("");
            }
            else {
                setGraphic(null); // Remove checkbox if row is empty
                setText("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Using CheckBoxTableCell

JavaFX API has this convenient class `CheckBoxTableCell` that would do all these for you. Most people find this class hard to use because there are 2 things that you need to ensure to use it correctly:

1. The `TableView` that the column belongs to must be editable.
2. The `TableColumn` itself must be editable.

Example:

```
tableView.setEditable(true);
tableColumnSelected.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(tableColumnSelected));
tableColumnSelected.setEditable(true);
```

As for whether which entry you want to be removed with the delete button, you just need to remove the correct items from the `TableView`.

Comment: Thank you so much! The setEditable example you gave solved my problem!